# Image in QGraphicsScene disappears when it is scaled above 32,767 pixels

Tags: c++, qt, graphics

I have a `QGraphicsScene` inside a `QGraphicsView` that displays a scaled pixmap. For some reason, when the pixmap is larger than 32,767 pixels (max value of type `int`), it fails to show up at all or sometimes partially shows up.

The `QGraphicsView` documentation for QT5 says:

*Note that although the scene supports a virtually unlimited size, the range of the scroll bars will never exceed the range of an integer (INT_MIN, INT_MAX).*

However, I should be able to display a pixmap larger than 32,767 pixels because INT_MIN = -2147483648, INT_MAX = 2147483647 on my system. What could cause the pixmap to not show up when it gets larger than 32,767 pixels in one dimension? As long as it's below 32,767 pixels, the image displays properly. Code below.

```
// Transformation matrix
QMatrix matrix;
if(!time_vertical) {
    matrix.scale(1, -1);
    matrix.rotate(90);
}
matrix.scale(frequency_zoom, time_zoom);
// Create pixmap
pixmap.convertFromImage(*image);
pixmap = pixmap.transformed(matrix);
// Add pixmap to scene
scene->clear();
QGraphicsPixmapItem* item = scene->addPixmap(pixmap);
item->setPos(0, 0); // Set pixmap origin (0, 0) in scene coordinates
scene->setSceneRect(pixmap.rect());
```

**More Info:** I'm using an intel processor on Ubuntu 14.04. I printed INT_MIN and INT_MAX in debug output so I'm sure of their values.

Comment: 32767 also happens to be SHORT_MAX for C/C++ type `short` which is signed by default.  Are you sure your code is not using short type somewhere (and you get overflow) also what CPU target are you ?  Intel? ARM?  What is the value of "matrix" in your example ?

Comment: some GDI functions are limited by short int ... for example `Ellipse` cant have multiplication of semiaxis larger then 32767... hinting that GDI use `16 bit int`s also for other stuff...